# Why does ssh-key work on one server but not on another?

Tags: ssh, putty

I have the problem that an ssh-connection with public-private-key authentication is working on 10 servers perfectly, but not on another.

The user is on all machines the same and the key-pair also. I can't figure out what the problem is. The error message is :

> No supported authentication methods available: Server sent public key.

The configuration is identical on all machines and the key is stored on every machine, I checked this several times.

To access it I use putty on a Windows machine.

Comment: Check permissions of the `~/.ssh` folders  on the faulty host

Comment: If the ~/.ssh readable to others, sshd will not read out of it.

Answer (score 0):

> No supported authentication methods available: Server sent public key.

This says that server is able to use pubkey authentication, but you didn't provide any key. Make sure that the key is configured in the client.